# Understanding code for sorting elements in an array

Tags: java, sorting

Please explain how the code on the lines 15-19 help in achieving sorting.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws java.io.IOException
{
    FastScanner scanner = new FastScanner(8000000);
    Writer writer = new Writer(System.out);      
    int T = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[1000000];     
    for(int index=0; index<T ;index++)
    {
        arr[scanner.nextInt()]++;
    }

   for( int index = 0; index<1000000 ;index++ )
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[index];j++)
        writer.writeln(index);
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

Comment: `lines 15-19` are not sorting at all ! They are just printing the sorted array !

Comment: Could you give this code some context? If I had to guess, I would say FastScanner is doing the sorting behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

This way of sorting is called [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

The "sorting" is happening here,

```
   10     for(int index=0; index<T ;index++)
   11    {
   12         arr[scanner.nextInt()]++;
   13     }
```

and NOT in lines 15-19.

This sorting works with this assumptions : All input values are in range `0` to `arr.length - 1`

As the input is read, the `index` of the array corresponding to the read value is incremented.

Finally, we loop through the array from index `0` onwards to `arr.length - 1`, printing the `index` of the array equal to the number of times it was read. This happens in lines 15-19

```
   15     for( int index = 0; index<1000000 ;index++ )
   16     {
   17         for(int j=0;j<arr[index];j++)
   18             writer.writeln(index);
   19     }
```

---

Example :
Input<sup>1</sup> : `2, 3, 5, 0, 4, 0, 3, 5`

Array will look like<sup>1</sup> : `{2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2}`

Printing index the number of time it occurs : `0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5`

---

<sup>1</sup> : Assumed that all input values are within the range 0 to 5. Hence the size of the array is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no sorting of the array, but the printing writes the elements of the array in sorted order. Take this example where we input 6 elements to the array (2, 3, 3, 5, 8 and 9) and see what happens in each iteration:

```
T = 6

arr[0] = 0
arr[1] = 0
arr[2] = 1
arr[3] = 2
arr[4] = 0
arr[5] = 1
arr[6] = 0
arr[7] = 0
arr[8] = 1
arr[9] = 1

index=0
j=0; j<0; j++

index=1
j=0; j<0; j++

index=2
j=0; j<1; j++
"2"

index=3
j=0; j<2; j++
"3" "3"

index=4
j=0; j<0; j++

index=5
j=0; j<1; j++
"5"

index=6
j=0; j<0; j++

index=7
j=0; j<0; j++

index=8
j=0; j<1; j++
"8"

index=9
j=0; j<1; j++
"9"

Output: 2 3 3 5 8 9
```

As you see, the elements are printed in sorted order, but the array itself is not ordered at all. (I didn't write the rest of the iterations as the elements are equal to 0 and you already know what happens in that case)